# external auto suggest extension for mediawiki?

Tags: mediawiki

I have an app with a support form that a customer can use to submit new issues.  One of the things that's been requested is to search their public wiki and automatically create suggestions based upon it (very similar to what SO does).  Since the page in question is outside of MediaWiki itself, I'm unsure about how to move forward.

My question is twofold:

Is there an out of the box extension to do this sort of thing?
If not, how would you recommend I go about doing it?  I've never written a MediaWiki extension, but for the experienced among you, what approach would you take?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if something like that already exists. But if I had to do it from scratch, I would definitely go on using the [mediawiki API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aSearch). Example here:

Show a list of 10 pages that contain the word MYSEARCHTEXTGOESHERE

```
http://mywiki.org/wiki/api.php?action=query&list=search&srsearch=MYSEARCHTEXTGOESHERE&srprop=timestamp
```

It wouldn't be an extension in the wiki, but rather a GET call to the wiki server from your app.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing.  I don't really like their API, and I think their search is just about worthless.  I ended up having to break down the sentences myself and then spawn a half dozen or so requests into the API to get a list of pages, and then go *back* to get the page information.  It's ridiculous that I cannot retrieve the URL to the page in the same request as the search.

Comment: else, you may create an RSS extension (with simplepie) that just outputs your desired content, and then you call the data from your app... not as simple, but it could work.